# Google Sheets Script setformula for Loop

Tags: google-apps-script

I have a Google Sheet that needs to contain a formula that changes depending on which row it is in, for 55 rows in a single column. The formula references a named data range (from another sheet) and pulls the correct value using an index call: =sum(index(jan,1))

I'm attempting to create a setFormula script that I can run each time I create a new column c so that I only need to rename the month to populate my values. It does not work.

```
function setFormulas() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();

  var map = [
    { locus: "C3", order: 1 },
    { locus: "C4", order: 2 },
    { locus: "C5", order: 3 },
    { locus: "C6", order: 4 },
    { locus: "C21", order: 19 },
  ];

  var i
  for (i = 1; i > 57; i++) {
    var ref = map[i].locus
    var cell = sheet.getCell(""+ref+"");
  cell.setFormula("=sum(index(jan,"+i+"))")
  }

}
```

I am completely new to java, so this is probably a legit butchering...

I want the script to loop through the range of cells C3 -> C56 and insert my formula, taking into consideration that each time the row value increases by 1, my index call needs to be correspondingly updated by 1 as well.

ArrayFormula instead?:

=ARRAYFORMULA(=SUM(INDEX(jan,1), INDEX(jan,55))) nope
=ARRAYFORMULA(=SUMIFS(C3:C56 .. I have no idea how to continue this. Named range is jan, column c will have sums of each row in sequence

Comment: I think you can pull this off just using an ArrayFormula. No need for a script. 

Here's a link to some reference documentation:
https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093275?hl=en

Comment: I've tried the arrayformula, but it doesn't seem to get the link between index row call and current row to propagate the changes..

Comment: Can you update your post with your attempts with ArrayFormula? I may be able to help you troubleshoot.